# Where is the injector circuit on a 2007 Toyota Yaris?

Tags: toyota, obd-ii, fuel-injectors, yaris, lpg

I have the PO201 error code which appears randomly every 30Km to 50 Km. The issue sounds possible as the car ran 2000Km with a damaged spark in cylinder 1 before repair.

However, they are no circuits plugged on injectors. They are connected directly to a set of wire. The ʟᴘɢ engine speed varies between 600 to 900 rpm every second and little less when on gasoline.
There is a small box with many pluggable electronics components near the left headlamps, but if it’s inside I’ve no idea each thing belongs to:[image][image]
From what I read (if I’m not wrong) this seems to be an amplifier for giving enough current to actually command the injector from the weak signal coming from the ᴇᴄᴜ.

Comment: So what are you asking?

Comment: @SolarMike the injectors were changed during previous repairs, so where is the part between the ecu and the first injector which needs to be replaced?

Answer (score 0):

The injector circuit is simply said the whole system that controls the injector, including the injector itself, quoting from https://www.obd-codes.com/p0201:

> P0201 means that the PCM detected a fault in the injector or the wiring to the injector.

It means the injector system anywhere from the ECU to the injector is faulty. It could be the wiring. It could be the amplifier. It could actually be the ECU. It could also be the injector.

I would say if the cylinder 1 had issues in the past life of the vehicle, it's more likely that the component near the issues (i.e. the injector) is faulty than the component far away from the injectors (let's say the wiring, amplifier or ECU) is faulty.

You could try switching the injector from cylinder 1 to some other cylinder, so that it uses the wiring and position of another cylinder. Then you'll see whether the problem code changes to the other cylinder.

Comment: I have no idea on how  to remove injectors.

Comment: @user2284570 Well, that's one option out. Me neither... But if the injectors were changed 2000km, ago, perhaps you could take the car to the shop that did the previous repair? I mean, surely there should be some sort of warranty on their work. It seems to me that one of the replaced injectors could be faulty.

Comment: 2000km was how long the damaged spark was there, whatever damaged spark really means, before repair - not how long since injectors changed which could have just been done...

Comment: I went for an engine change but the shop wasn't able to do it in full. They drove almost 400km in tests burning half of a filled gas tank without being able to fix all problems because of lack of knowledge. Toyota isn t enjoyed at the idea of warranting their repairs based on the previous work of someone else.

Comment: @user2284570 I’m having trouble trying to work out what you mean from what you say... “how does Toyota **enjoy** warranty” ??

Comment: @SolarMike at first glance Toyota considered the work of their competitor repair shop to be really a mess (and as they were unsuccessful at finishing to change the engine it’s difficult to prove them wrong), so they refused to work on the engine on the ground that because while they warrant their repairs they would refuse to offer warranty on such kind of mess and thus refuse to touch it (the fact the previous repair shop which changed the engine didn’t fixed the injector circuit is far to be the only problem).

Comment: I can understand their position - if the other repairs have been so poor, then they would have to replace / repair things that they did not work on which will cost them more than the job is worth... So, looks like you have to take it back to the people who did the poor repairs - cheap is not often the best ...

Comment: @SolarMike this is what I did, they ended up driving almost 400Km in testing without being able to change anything (I took my car back with 15 Liters of gas less than when I deposited). The previous repair shop all simply lack the knowledge to fix the remaining issues (they told me they aren’t being able to do more). At that point they are at the level of asking questions on https://mechanics.stackexchange.com which something I can do myself.