# Ways to maintain the ᴍɪʟ disabled on a 2007 Yaris Volkswagen scandal like…

Tags: toyota, obd-ii, yaris, lpg, mil

Well it’s a strange problem after taking the cheapest repair shop of the city where currently anything is not from me yet :

- engine speed is unstable after 70℃ on gasoline and 55℃ on ʟᴘɢ mode and air conditioning switched off in both cases : [image]
- **The ᴍɪʟ is always on on ᴏʙᴅ data but it gets light off on the dashboard after ignition is turned on** (contradictory and very strange I know but this proves my question might be possible).
- They are 2 problems which makes the ᴍɪʟ signaling :
  P0328 (changing the knock sensor didn’t solve it) and
  P0103 which is described as `Mass or air Flow High Input` (no idea of what it is and what’s the additional steps to diagnose and repair shops says “just asks Toyota repair services”). Clearing those problems along the ᴍɪʟ doesn’t help as they get back 3 seconds after turning ignition on.

## Legal issues :

Because of the way the work of the previous repair shop was done, Toyota is refusing to repair the car and the previous repair shop definitely lack the knowledge for it (I insisted and they tried many times and failed and don’t know someone who can fix issues excepting Toyota).

But the car is imported from an other European country, in order to register it in my country, you need the foreign registration certificate. But Italy now requires to destroys registration certificate for being able to export cars. So the trick is I used the selling contract to establish a temporary registration certificate in my country (something possible only one time), I need it being valid for passing the Vehicle inspection test (it’s valid 6 months until 20 April). But the vehicle inspection test will fails if the ᴍɪʟ is on. A successful inspection test is required for registering the car definitely. The last deadline I could get for inspection is tomorrow at 11H15 GMT. So if the ᴍɪʟ is still on at that hour, the car will be in practice definitely banned from public roads even if the problem is fixed later.

## What I want :

So with a good number of professionals being unable to fix the errors which sound to be Toyota specific, at that point, I have only one focus : get the ᴍɪʟ off during the inspection test tomorrow, even if it’s for 3 minutes and would work only on a cold engine.
I mean to disable the ᴍɪʟ **without fixing the underlying problems**. Legally, the ᴏʙᴅ can still report the error codes, but if it does, the ᴍɪʟ needs to be off on ᴏʙᴅ as it is on the dashboard.
I know this would result in the insurance being voided in case of an accident which is illegal, but it would get back to normal after fixing the underlying issues at a later date. The most important is to be able to register it before the last deadline as I don’t have the time to find someone or get the car repaired by Toyota (nor I know how to solve them myself).

If it can help, the ʟᴘɢ ᴇᴄᴜ is Stargas Pegasus 24, I talked to a Stargas installer, and he confirms that the ʟᴘɢ ᴇᴄᴜ is disabled when being on gasoline mode.
**I also have a raw ᴏʙᴅ access : I mean I can send arbitrary sequences of bytes to the car.**

Comment: Disabling the ᴍɪʟ without fixing the underlying problems is already done for the dashboard, even if it’s only a coincidence.

Comment: Also see this question : https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/65415/10976

Comment: @SolarMike this problem you are refering in the other question is so random that if I clear it I am almost sure it won t appear during the short period of the test.

Comment: The problem I'm having with your premise of "Toyota won't fix this" is, the dealership *will* fix it ... they just won't do it under warranty. If the dealership you took it to won't attempt to fix it, take it to a different dealership. If you are stone cold sure the dealership can fix it, they can and will fix it, it will just cost you money to make it happen. Considering what it is, you could end up paying a substantial sum. JMHO.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 no. I proposed them to sign a paper stating I bear reponsability in case of accident and reject warrenty, and Toyota still refuse even in that case. It s not even a question of money at that point. I recognize they are exagerating.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I would guess it has nothing to do with money at all. More likely, when the Toyota dealership gets its next scheduled audit from Toyota's quality control department, they will have to explain why they were working on a car that seems to have been imported via a legal loophole, and was then deliberately made unroadworthy by its owner before being properly registered, by getting work done elsewhere. The reason Toyota (and other Far East car manufacturers) are successful businesses is *because that's the way their corporate culture works, for anything related to quality.*

Comment: … of course the dealership (or even another back street repair shop) *can* fix it - a complete engine replacement should do the job! But I guess the OP was still looking for a cheap option - at least till he/she ran out of time.

Comment: @alephzero though the someone else work have the required certification for getting repairs accepted by inssurance compagnies (that s why you can t repair your car yourself in practice).So it shouldn t supposed to happen, nd if it does, the inussurance will sue the repair shop (which is likely to happen as I asked the scrapping procedure damage though I m still looking for a legal solution to be able to run the car).Legally Italy was sentenced several times in European courts for their legislation restricting car exports.I guess they found the definite showstopper for stopping prise increase.

Comment: @alephzero at that point I’m not even sure Toyota want to hear of a replacement engine (despite the current one being new and under warranty). Others repair shop accepts to work on the car provided they are allowed to work with ʟᴘɢ, but they don’t know how to fix those Toyota specifics issues.